# Nhibernate, Criteria List as search parameters

Tags: list, nhibernate, hibernate-criteria, ilist

Basically what I am trying to do is retrieve an officer. I call this method and pass a IList of Officer Ids. what I want to do it use that Ilist which will have a number of unique ids in it. to pull the one record for each id into a IList of officers which i return and do stuff with.

My problem is that I can not for the life of me figure out how to get the restrictions correct. so say the list has 3 , 6 , 9 and 12 in it it would get all of these records.

```
    public IList<Officer> GetOfficer(IList<int> OfficerId)
    {
        return session.CreateCriteria<Officer>()
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("OfficerId", OfficerId))
                .SetCacheable(true)
                .List<Officer>();
    }
```

any help would be greatly appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution should be in `InExpression`:

```
public IList<Officer> GetOfficer(IList<int> OfficerId)
{
  return session.CreateCriteria<Officer>()
    .Add(new NHibernate.Criterion.InExpression("OfficerId"
               , OfficerId.Cast<object>().ToArray()))
    .SetCacheable(true)
    .List<Officer>();
}
```